# Salvar estado do togglebuttom

Tags: android

Boa tarde!

Como eu poderia salvar o estado de um togglebuttom, criei um app onde eu salvo e apago um edittext, no entanto não sei como salvar o estado desse botão, toda vez que eu saiu do app e volto o botão seria para estar no modo apagar, porém ele retorna no modo salvar.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda de como fazer?

Comment: Qual o código que usa para salvar o EditText?

Comment: Usei SharedPreferences. Implementei o exemplo abaixo e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) para salvar / obter o estado do `ToggleButton` (checked / unchecked)

Ao iniciar a activity, verifique nas preferências o valor salvo, e programaticamente altere o estado do botão de acordo.

```
final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // Contexto

ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggleButton.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("meuToggleButton", false));
...
```

Para salvar o valor nas preferências, utilize o [OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html), dessa forma, sempre que o botão for clicado seu valor será salvo (e posteriormente lido ao iniciar a activity)

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("meuToggleButton", isChecked);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado, utilizei o exemplo acima e deu certo.

Comment: Bem-vindo.
Estou contente por ter ajudado. Se a resposta solucionou o problema, por favor, [aceite-a](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).